# PHP Slim framework changing page

Tags: php, redirect, slim, slim-lang

I'm new to slim and MVC and i'm trying to get my head around changing pages on my website.

Currently using the code below when I access my index page it will change the view to be my projects page, however when it does this it doesn't change the URL at all.

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args) use($app)
{
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'projects.phtml', $args);
});
```

The url also stays as localhost/mywebsite

So my question is how do I get it to change the URL along with the view so that it becomes

localhost/mywebsite/projects

I've got the below code so that when someone goes to that url it becomes the projects page but I can't figure out how to redirect the user.

```
$app->get('/projects', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app)
{
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'projects.phtml', $args);
});
```

When I tried using

```
$app->response->redirect('/projects', 303);
```

It says method redirect not found in class.

Am I missing something obvious or am I making this completely wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withRedirect()` function of `$response` object

```
$app->get('/', function($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withRedirect('/projetcs');
});
```